# Where can I find the PyCharm source method signatures?

Tags: python, numpy, pycharm, numpy-ndarray, linter

I have a subclass that overrides `__setstate__` and PyCharm keeps displaying the following message:

`Signature of method A.__setstate__() does not match signature of base method in class 'np.ndarray'`

Where are the files located that PyCharm uses for this comparison? I cannot find in NumPy source (through their GitHub and my installation) where `__setstate__` has the signature that PyCharm is saying it must have.

Answer (score 0):

Try navigating to it via `Ctrl+U`/`Cmd+U` or icon on the gutter: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/navigating-through-the-source-code.html#go_to_implementation